# jqgrid: Tooltip for "Select All" checkbox

Tags: jqgrid

I am new to jqgrid. I need to show a tooltip for "Select All" checkbox in the column header so that the tooltip shows up when users hover mouse over the "Select All" checkbox. Please help. Here is the code that generate my grid.

```
jQuery("#ListContacts").jqGrid({
    data: jqgrid_data,
    datatype: "local",
    height: '700',
    width:'700',
    colNames: ['ContactID', 'Contact Name', 'Cell', 'Office', 'Email', 'Address'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'ContactID', index: 'ContactID', hidden: true },
        { name: 'ContactName', index: 'Contact Name', width: 120, cellattr: Soars.JQGridHelper.wrapContents },
        { name: 'Cell', index: 'Cell', align: "right", width: 400 },
        { name: 'Office', index: 'Office', align: "right", width: 40 },
        { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', align: "right", align: "center", width: 50 },
        { name: 'Address', index: 'Address',  width: 60, datefmt: 'm/d/y', formatter: Soars.JQGridHelper.dateFormat, unformat: Soars.JQGridHelper.dateUnFormat }],
    rowNum: 25,
    rowList: [25, 50, 75, 100],
    altRows: true,
    pager: '#pager_ListContacts',
    pagerpos: 'left',
    recordpos: 'right',
    sortname: 'ContactID',
    viewrecords: true,
    emptyrecords: "No records to view",
    sortorder: "asc",
    multiselect: true,
    multiselectWidth: 16,
    headertitles:true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just set the `title` attribute of the checkbox. The id of the chechbox is build based on the id of the grid, but with `"cb_"` prefix. If the id of the grid is `"list"`, for example, then the code

```js
$("#cb_list").attr("title", "Select All");
```

executed after the grid will created the tooltip.

Comment: I do not have a separate checkbox list in the grid. I am using the inbuilt check boxes to select rows in the jqgrid. It will be nice if you can elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: @AndyH: What you mean under "Select All" checkbox then? If you place the checkbox yourself in the column header, then you need just include `title` attribute. It's better that you include some JavaScript code, which explains how you create and fill the grid.

Comment: I have updated my question with the actual code. Please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: @AndyH: You do use `multiselect: true` and you probably mean under "Select All" the checkbox in the multiselect column. Thus my initial answer is exactly what you need to do. Just append your code with the line  `$("#cb_ListContacts").attr("title", "Select All");`. Please write in all question about jqGrid which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). I develop free jqGrid, where I can help mostly.